# What is the best way to get my solutions of a set of problems revised?

Tags: discussion

I don't know if it is appropriate to post a big list of my homework Problems and expect that somebody corrects it or gives me some Feedback About it.

Assume I have solved 20 Problems and I am unsure about 10 of them what can I do to see if my Solutions are correct? Under which tag should I post the solutions. Can I work with bounties to get a revision?

Comment: I do not believe that this fits with the format of the site. Concise, targeted questions about points that you're unsure of or don't understand are good, but extensive reviews of your work are likely off-topic. If you really want detailed feedback on so much volume, then you should really direct it to your teacher/professor/tutor (or go to something closer to a discussion forum).

Comment: The best way to get corrections to your solutions to a set of problems is to ask your teacher/instructor/professor/TA (if you are in a course) or perhaps to hire a tutor. It is not appropriate to post a question with a list of your attempted solutions. It may be appropriate to post a question to figure out how to do some problem you're having trouble with.

Comment: If you are unsure about your solutions, then you haven't learned the material. Go back and study until you can tell for sure whether your solutions are correct.

Answer (score 5):

We aren't really a solution verification site. It's better to compare notes with a classmate or seek help from a tutor for that type of thing.

What you can do here is try to isolate what you're conceptually unsure of and ask a question specifically about that. You're probably reasonably sure about *most* steps in your answer, right? It isn't hard to check your calculations line by line. Your lack of certainty probably comes from a particular step where you assumed something or arrived at a conclusion that you're not sure about. Asking a question about that step is generally ok, especially if you generalize it. It may also lead you to a solution before you finish writing it.

You can also ask a question about how to know if you are right. For example, with some elaboration, "How can I verify if I have factored a polynomial correctly?" would be an acceptable question here.